# How to take a webpage's content to create a native app for it? e.i not just a webview of the website

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create an app for a website that I don't own, like youtube or reddit. Every time I search for help, all I keep getting is how to create a webview. I've done that but that's not what I want. I want to take the website's content and create an app with it, like create my own buttons and such. I want to *convert* a website into an app.

I was thinking of somehow loading the website in the background and creating activities/buttons/intents that basically do what the webpage does but I don't know how to go about that or if there's a better way.

Thank you in advance.

Please let me know if clarification is needed.

Comment: This is hard because "no such answer fits for all" on this task because every website is structured differently and parsing its HTLM needs an understanding on the website DOM structure honestly that is just the first Calvary because deciding which view to use is not an easy thing.

Comment: If you are still interested investing time for it you can look for `Jsoup` topic for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i got -3 votes for some reason and it has been 12 hours since i posted this question, i'm guessing the question has been consumed by the abyss of questions by now.

I made a reddit post and got some responses:

one user:
The term you’re looking for is “web scraping“ or “site scraping”. I think that’s probably what you need to research before you’re ready to handle how to make that into an app.

That’s a good starting point and once you have the content from scraping, making the app is no different than any other app.

second user:
If the website has a public (or private) API, you can use your buttons and networking calls to their API to build your client app. You are building a "YouTube client" in this case using the YouTube API.

If they dont have an API and you don't want to display their website, what you are doing is trying to reverse engineer their website and hijack the UI which is not a good practice and may even be illegal depending on the site and terms.

third user:
@second user is right on the money, but one thing I'll like to add is, the goal is to get data off of the website so that you can use in your app. An API is one (convenient) way of doing that but others are,

```
RSS or similar feed content (prefer this if there website supports)
HTML scraping
```

The above two will require you store the data somewhere else (and possible expose an API instead) because of technical reasons: you don't have access to older entries in RSS feeds and it's atrocious to keep on scraping everytime you need to access the website data. They can be done on the client (mobile app) but are best done on a server. This means you might need to get your hands dirty writing server code but you don't have to.

/thread

I'm going to do research on website scrapping and APIs to see which route i should go.

Hopefully this helped someone else.